# Extracting difficult words from text

Tags: nlp

I need to identify difficult words from input text. I do not want to use common word lists because the level of difficulty will need to be set for children. Is there a scoring mechanism that computes the difficulty level of each word? I can use a threshold for score to separate difficult words from easy ones. The end objective is to provide word meanings for all such difficult words.

There are several ways in which overall text can be scored for complexity or difficulty level, eg. The Dale–Chall formula, The Gunning fog formula, etc. However, these are used for defining "readability" i.e. the ease with which a reader can understand the written text. My requirement is related to the difficulty level of individual words in a text.

There are a few methods that I have come across for defining difficult words such words with more than 2 syllables or any word not appearing in the 10000 most common words, etc. However, none of these methods are useful for me. I am trying to build an application that can identify difficult words, and provides relevant dictionary meanings for only those words. Is there a scoring mechanism that will allow me to use a threshold to separate the difficult words from the easy ones?

Comment: What do you call a difficult word ? Is *abbreviation* difficult ? Is *thee* difficult ? What about *coronavirus* ? And *bye-bye* ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust - I have added more clarity to the question and also the research I have already done on the subject. thanks.

Comment: You could find a corpus of children's stories and a corpus of stories for adults and compare frequency of words in each. Some similar research [https://www.sketchengine.eu/wp-content/uploads/Beebox_2013.pdf](here). Sometimes though a word is 'difficult' because of the context in which it's used.

Comment: @Yves Daoust - If you re-read my question, you will understand that that is exactly what my question is. Is there a way to DEFINE a difficult word other than by merely using the number of syllables in the word or whether it appears in the most common English words.

Comment: @Yves Daoust - Let me clarify a bit further. From a conceptual point of view, a difficult word will be any word that an age-appropriate reader of a particular text (say a para from a book meant for 8-12 years old) would struggle to understand. Obviously, the same word may not be a difficult word for, let's say, a 21 year old reader. That is why I thought it would have been great to have a scoring mechanism for the difficulty level of a word and then use a threshold for separating difficult word. The threshold will be higher for a 21 year old compared to a reader in the 8-12 year old age group.

Comment: I have found considerable material for "readability" of text where a similar scoring mechanism is used, but haven't been able to find any on individual words. I hope this clarifies. thanks

Comment: Even a team of linguists and psychologists would not agree on the concept. So what could a poor computer algorithm do ?

Comment: What you are asking is like "please what is the program to tell if a painting is a masterpiece ?".

Comment: @Yves Daoust – Thank you for your comments and probing questions as they are forcing me to think a lot more deeply about the problem I am trying to solve. However, while I agree with you that the question requires a qualitative assessment which is not easy, I am a lot more optimistic than you on the potential of using computer algorithms for solving such problems. If algorithms can be used for predicting prices of masterpieces and wines, then I am reasonably sure that an algorithm can be used for scoring difficulty level of words.

Comment: I guess the key is to find good ‘predictors’ for difficulty. As I have already referred in my question as well as comments, there are rudimentary approaches that have used, such as number of syllables or rarity of the word, as a proxy for difficulty. My question was to explore if there are other more sophisticated approaches in natural language processing that I may not have come across. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ Ian Mercer – thank you for the article. I think it’s a great idea to score based on rarity of the word in children’s literature. I will be working on this approach and combine it with other approaches- such as the number of syllables – to arrive at a composite score.

Comment: There are no algorithms to rate paintings by looking at them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:No._5,_1948.jpg

Wine rating requires a full database of references, no algorithm.